# Evaluate $\int \frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^6+3x^4+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral
$$\int \frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^6+3x^4+x^2}}dx$$
Since $(x^3-x)'=x^2-1$, I tried to write $x^6+3x^4+x^2$ as a function of $(x^3-x)$.

Comment: $(x^3-x)'=3x^2-1$.

Answer (score 7):

Observe that $$\int\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^6+3x^4+x^2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + 1}}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx = \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2}},$$
where $y := x + x^{-1}$. I think you can take it from here.

Comment: Yes I can.Thank you!

Comment: It has been tacitly assumed $$\sqrt{x^2}=x$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No, that is not what I have done. I have pulled a factor of $x^4$  out of the square root, and used the fact that $\sqrt{x^4} = x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.